# OpenTK VBO Drawing

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I would like make my own model viewer.

I can get normals and vertices from a model and send them to arrays. I would like use triangle type to draw.

`normalBuffer[k]` represents the normal of a triangle. This triangle points are inside of the `vertexBuffer` array. In this array, `vertBuffer[k]`, `vertBuffer[k+1]`, `vertBuffer[k+2]` make up a triangle.

If I use the below code to draw my model it works very well.

```
if (vertBuffer != null)    
        {    
            for (int k = 0; k < vertBuffer.Length; k += 3)    
            {    
                GL.Normal3(normalBuffer[k / 3]);    
                GL.Vertex3(vertBuffer[k]);    
                GL.Vertex3(vertBuffer[k + 1]);    
                GL.Vertex3(vertBuffer[k + 2]);    
            }    
        }
```

So my question is how can I draw my model with VBO (`GL.BindData` Method). This makes me confused when I want to implement normals with vertices..

Comment: I suggest looking for a tutorial. The answer to your question will most likely exceed what can be answered here on SO.

Comment: Your question has a clear indication that you haven't made a minimal research on the topic.The internet is full of tutorials regarding usage of VBOs. I am sure if you take time to read some of them you won't have to spend your time asking here for help.

Comment: I was gave many try to do it but i am not able to use normal while drawing. If i don't use normal implementation i can draw but lighting (According to normals) is not shown as well. For example first triangle normal is not implent as first normal. Something wrong. Also I'm beginner at GL control. This is why i asking this question..